# Redirecting to new page in response to Socket.IO event

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'm developing a multi-page web application with Express that has chat functionality (powered by Socket.IO). Users can invite others to a private shared chatroom (that also has other components like a shared drawing board). I'd like to redirect both of the users (inviter and invitee) to a different URL upon completing the invitation transaction.

Since socket.io doesn't have access to the request and response objects of my routes, I attempted to pass my instance of socket.io into my route handling. Issues of duplicate event handlers piling up on page refresh aside, Express throws an error when trying to do a redirect after the response has already been sent (this makes sense).

It seems like the only way to achieve this would be to have the redirect occur on the client, with the new chatroom URL being passed to each from Socket.IO. Relying on the client for state transfer seems too fragile, though.

Are there any other options? What is the best way to implement what I'm after?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not so sure it would be too fragile to do in the client.  Just send the URL over the socket and either do `window.location.href = redirectUrl` or `$('div').load(newContentUrl)` with jQuery.